# How do you organize your code for Angular app? (code organisation patterns)

Tags: angular

I am struggling with the best pattern for code structure in my Angular app.

I have a project which contains more modules; every module has components tests, etc..

```
/app
    /commons
        /components
        /constants
            constant-1.constant.ts
            constant-2.constant.ts
            constant-3.constant.ts
            constant-4.constant.ts
            ...
        /helpers
            helper-1.helper.ts
            helper-2.helper.ts    
            ...
    /module-name-1
         /commons
             /helpers
             /constants
         /component-name-1
            /component-name-subcomponent-1
               component-name-subcomponent-1.component.ts
         /component-name-2
            component-name-subcomponent-2.component.ts   
         module-name-1.module.ts
         module-name-1-routing.module.ts
```

This is how my code organization looks like. I would like to ask you, how do you struggle with some shared/common parts as constants/functions/helpers... Eg. constants - I tried to keep shared constants in one folder in the module, or if they are shared between modules, in the app path. But sometimes, I use constant just in one component, or 2 of them, and then I have followed by components tree to some far away shared folder where i have defined two lines of code. The same with interfaces - i keep all of them in one folder, but sometimes interface is used just in one component, or sometimes in their childs. How do you organize it? What is the best practice for bigger projects?

I wonder about one commons/ folder in-app route, with the similar structure as rest of app /module/component/ and there keeps interfaces and constants related to the components and keep a common path to them - but when I tried it - it also messed, and there are no helpful tools to manage it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This question will have highly opinionated answers, but according to 
angular style guide one should have a angular app architecture like this :

```
|-- app
         |--Feature Modules Folder
           |-- Feature-1 Module  // comprising of feature-1 components
               |-- [+] components
               |-- [+] services // service provide by feature module
               |-- feature-1-routing.module.ts
               |-- feature-1.module.ts
         |-- Core Module Folder // all core functionality and singleton services 
           which will be imported by root module and consist of no exports
           |-- [+] authentication
           |-- [+] footer
           |-- [+] guards
           |-- [+] http
           |-- [+] interceptors
           |-- [+] mocks
           |-- [+] services
           |-- [+] header
           |-- core.module.ts
           |-- logger.service.ts
         |-- Shared Module Folder // this modules containes components 
              etc which are used multiple times across the app, Shared 
              Module is imported by Features Module
              |-- [+] components
              |-- [+] directives
              |-- [+] pipes
              |-- [+] models
              |-- SharedModule.module.ts
         |-- [+] configs
    |-- assets
         |-- scss/ css
              |-- styles.scss/styles.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like a structure like this:

```
/app
    /components
        /page-components
            /home
            /contact
        /page-element-components
            /form
               ...
               ...
            /pop-ups
               ...
               ...
            /wizards
               ...
    /Services
        /global-services
            ...
            ... 
        /http-services
            ...
            ... 
    /Modules
        /app.module.ts
        /lazy-modules
            ...
            ... 
        /shared-modules
            ...
            ... 
    /Utils
        /helpers
            ...
            ... 
        /form-validators
        /pipes
    /Assets
        /global-styling
        /icons
```